# How to merge the result of this 2 queries in mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql

I am actually stuck in merging the result of this two queries:

first query:

```
SELECT c.code, c.name, pc.sku, pc.cat_code, pp.title 
FROM `cat_parent`  cp, cat c, prod_cat pc, products pp 
WHERE c.code = cp.cat_code 
  AND cp.cat_code = pc.cat_code 
  AND pp.sku = pc.sku 
  AND cp.parent_code = 01110 
  AND hide =0
```

The result I get is:

[image]

Second query:

```
SELECT `sku` , `update_date` , `description` , count( * ) AS total_sold 
FROM `orderline` 
WHERE `update_date` >= ( DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -14 DAY ) ) 
  AND `update_date` <= ( DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -7 DAY ) ) 
GROUP BY left( sku, 7 ) 
ORDER BY total_sold DESC
```

The result:
[image]

The question I want to ask that how can I get the result by filtering the sku available in both tables.

Just bit confused on that part....any ideas will be appreciated.

This is only part of the data. there is heaps of data. Yes, I want to merge the both tables and want to find the common sku available in both tables.

My expected result will be sku, title, total sold.

Thanks, anyway I managed to get around to get the result.

My final query:

> SELECT * FROM (
>
> SELECT `sku` , `update_date` , `description` FROM `orderline` WHERE
>   `update_date` >= '2012-03-06' AND `update_date` <= '2012-03-07' )g
>   JOIN (
>
> SELECT c.code, c.name, pc.sku, pc.cat_code FROM `cat_parent` cp, cat
>   c, prod_cat pc, products pp WHERE c.code = cp.cat_code AND cp.cat_code
>   = pc.cat_code AND pp.sku = pc.sku AND cp.parent_code =01110 AND hide =0 )p ON left( g.sku, 7 ) = left( p.sku, 7 )

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to filter sku. Filter how? Join the queries where sku is the same?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you want to merge the two datasets and then filter by the sku column?

Comment: to clarify, you want these two tables to be merged into a single table so that you can filter against one result set? Also great timing abe/msonic, all of us commented around the same time lol

Comment: @jazzrai: I think just adding your expected result based on your sample data would help us understand what you're looking for

Comment: need a relation between two query to join... from result set its unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this -

```
SELECT
    `c`.`code`, `c`.`name`, `pc`.`sku`, `pc`.`cat_code`, `pp.title`,
    `ol`.`sku`, `ol`.`update_date`, `ol`.`description`, COUNT(*) AS `total_sold`
FROM `cat_parent` `cp`
INNER JOIN `cat` `c`
    ON `c`.`code` = `cp`.`cat_code`
INNER JOIN `prod_cat` `pc`
    ON `cp`.`cat_code` = `pc`.`cat_code`
INNER JOIN `products` `pp`
    ON `pp`.`sku` = `pc`.`sku`
INNER JOIN `orderline` `ol`
    ON LEFT(`pc`.`sku`, 7) = LEFT(`ol`.`sku`, 7)
WHERE `cp`.`parent_code` = 01110
AND `hide` = 0
AND `ol`.`update_date` >= ( DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -14 DAY ) )
AND `ol`.`update_date` <= ( DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -7 DAY ) )
GROUP BY left( `ol`.`sku`, 7 )
ORDER BY `total_sold` DESC
```